# What is the difference between 'git diff --staged' and 'git diff --cached'?

Tags: git, git-diff

I know both commands show the difference between staged files and last commit. If so, why git having 2 different commands for the same task?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the documentation of `git diff`. Its very well explained.

> git diff [--options] --cached [] [--] […] This form is
>   to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the
>   named . Typically you would want comparison with the latest
>   commit, so if you do not give , it defaults to HEAD. If HEAD
>   does not exist (e.g. unborn branches) and  is not given, it
>   shows all staged changes. **--staged is a synonym of --cached**.

So you can see its only a synonym.

Answer (score 0):

To see the changes that have been staged already, you can pass the `-–staged` option to `git diff` (in pre-1.6 versions of Git, use `–-cached`). It just a synonym!